# ASP.Net Identity Custom Field Losing Value on Create User

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

So, I have an interesting issue with MVC5, EF6 and ASP.Net Identity. I've added a custom field to the ApplicationUser but when I attempt to create a new user with UserManager.CreateAsync() I get the following error:

The 'IsConfirmed' property on 'ApplicationUser' could not be set to a 'null' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'System.Boolean'.

Note: When debugging user.IsConfirmed is not null has the value false as it should.

The code in question is as follows:

```
ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser()
{
     UserName = model.UserName,
     Email = model.Email,
     ConfirmationToken = confirmationToken,
     IsConfirmed = false
};

IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

And the definition of AplicationUser:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
     public string Email { get; set; }
     public string ConfirmationToken { get; set; }
     public bool IsConfirmed { get; set; }
}
```

Finally, the stack trace:

```
[ConstraintException: The 'IsConfirmed' property on 'ApplicationUser' could not be set to a 'null' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'System.Boolean'. ]
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.ErrorHandlingValueReader`1.GetValue(DbDataReader reader, Int32 ordinal) +152
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.GetPropertyValueWithErrorHandling(Int32 ordinal, String propertyName, String typeName) +95
   lambda_method(Closure , Shaper ) +1007
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.HandleEntityAppendOnly(Func`2 constructEntityDelegate, EntityKey entityKey, EntitySet entitySet) +737
   lambda_method(Closure , Shaper ) +501
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper shaper) +281
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext() +105
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext() +52
   System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source) +164
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.<GetElementFunction>b__1(IEnumerable`1 sequence) +83
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle(IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot) +107
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression) +197
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.DbQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression) +149
   System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault(IQueryable`1 source) +251
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore`1.FindByNameAsync(String userName) +1174
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.<FindByNameAsync>d__d.MoveNext() +231
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() +24
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.<ValidateUserName>d__0.MoveNext() +832
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() +21
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.<ValidateAsync>d__4.MoveNext() +433
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() +24
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.<CreateAsync>d__0.MoveNext() +629
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() +24
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.<CreateAsync>d__10.MoveNext() +883
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() +24
   L33THub.Web.Controllers.<Register>d__d.MoveNext() in c:\Users\rwn\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\L33THub\L33THub.Web\Controllers\AccountController.cs:121
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() +21
   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.ThrowIfFaulted(Task task) +61
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +114
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeAsynchronousActionMethod>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +66
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +136
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +102
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +117
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass48.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__41() +323
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +136
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +102
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +72
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +185
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +38
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9514812
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Comment: That's my sense as well. Hopefully someone sees something we're missing though. :(

Comment: I came across the same message once, but I don't remember how I got it fixed  8-))  Speaking of custom fields, I found this article useful: http://typecastexception.com/post/2013/10/27/Configuring-Db-Connection-and-Code-First-Migration-for-Identity-Accounts-in-ASPNET-MVC-5-and-Visual-Studio-2013.aspx. What if you made the field nullable or use defaults in the database?

Comment: I definitely don't ever want it to be null, but a default value would probably work. I'll give that a shot. Thanks! :)

Comment: Nope, it works fine if I add your custom fields. So fire off SQL profiler and try to see what query is sent to the server. Did you migrate your changes to the ApplicationUser model?

Comment: I added a constructor to the ApplicationUser and set IsConfirmed to false there. No dice.

Comment: @ADNow Thanks for your input! It definitely pointed me in the right direction. As it turns out, and this was a noob oversight on my part, but I neglected to give all of the existing records default values for the new custom fields. Probably the obscurity of the error I was receiving threw me off. Either way, the SQL profiler will be the first place I go when these kind of errors come up in the future. Thanks! :)

Comment: I had a stored procedure running on null fields and expecting values. *

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so...a bit embarrassing but the reason this was failing is that I had stored procedures trying to grab the values of null fields because I never cleared out the user store before testing and was using the same usernames. I had taken about a two week break between efforts on this project, but still...oops. :P Thank you to all the patient souls who helped me through this.